# Can´t click() on selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, click, selenium-chromedriver

I´m trying to scrape some websites with selenium. Up until now I was using PhantomJS and BSoup but with some webs it doesn´t work, so I´m on a diferent path now. One which apparently doesn´t work and I don´t know why, because I´ve following the same structure of some other posts about the issue.

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Visente\Desktop\Pablito 
Python\chromedriver.exe")

urlbet='https://www.bet365.es/?&cb=103265469#/HO/'

browser.get(urlbet)

sport=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dv1"]/a'))

sport.click()
```

This sets an error on the last line, when trying to do the click. After running the code, the error I get is

sport.click()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind. Apparently, there was one ")" missing before the last line, so it didn´t work properly. If anybody ahappens to have a similar mistake, be sure to check the wording.